# How can i solve this problem with k-loop inside other loop

Tags: c, loops

I just started learning C. I have trouble solving some problem.
So this is what i have to do.

n = 3

[image]

n=5

[image]

So basically you have 2 spaces just before first o, and after last o, no matter which value n has. U can see my code, it will be easier to undestand. 
So I have problem, with these o's. Can u look at my code and tell me whats the problem. I think it is something with the k-loop. It works for 3, but if n is more than 3, loop repeats one more time(i think so) and it causes problem.
Code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
int i,j,k,n;
printf("Unesi broj n: ");
scanf("%d",&n);

printf("+--");
for(i=0;i<(2*n-1);i++) printf("-");
printf("--+");
printf("\n");

for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(j=0;j<n;j++){
              if((i>0 || i<n) && j==0) printf("|  ");
              else if((i>0 || i<n) && j==n-1){
                    if(i%2==0) printf("  >");
                    else if(i%2==1) printf("  <");
                    }
             else { 
                for(k=0;k<n;k++){
                    if(k==n-1) printf("o");
                    else printf("o ");
                }
             }
        }
        printf("\n");
}

printf("+--");
for(i=0;i<(2*n-1);i++) printf("-");
printf("--+");
printf("\n");

return 0;
}
```

Comment: So you have print a pattern of n x n o-s with them being enclosed with characters as shown? It doesn't seem to work for n=1 and n=2 as well.

Comment: `(i>0 || i<n)` looks wrong. Maybe you meant `(i>0 && i<n)`?
But that could be reduced to `i>0` in your code i think.

Comment: @Osiris yep i meant that. i didnt see it at all. thanks buddy

Comment: @Osiris hahaha i>0 || i<n doesent have sense but it works. i mean with && it doesent. neither reducint it to i>0

Comment: @farC But it has no effect at all since `i<n` is also the loop condition. It was just a wild guess because it looked strange.

Comment: @div0man and Osiris thanks guys. I never thought i'll get answer in 20 mins haha xD

Comment: You're welcome, and welcome to StackExchange! If you'll hang around more, also note that comments are intended for clarification around the Q&A and not for thank-yous :)

Comment: okay sorry. my first post. wont happen anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `k`, don't make your job harder than it has to be :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int i,j,n;
    printf("Unesi broj n: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);


    // print the top edge
    printf("+--");
    for(i=0;i<(2*n-1);i++) printf("-");
    printf("--+");
    printf("\n");

    // row loop, only inner rows
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
            // every inner column starts with "|  " so no need to put this in the column loop
            printf("|  ");
            // column loop, here you just need to print the o-s
            for(j=0;j<n;j++){
                printf("o ");
            }
            // every inner column ends with " >" or " <" so no need to put this in the column loop, and one space will be included with the last o
            if (i % 2 == 0)
                printf(" >");
            else
                printf(" <");
            printf("\n");
    }

    // print the bottom edge
    printf("+--");
    for(i=0;i<(2*n-1);i++) printf("-");
    printf("--+");
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```